# UITableViewCell with all subviews disappears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I placed `UITableViewCell` with `UITextField` as `UITableView's` tableHeaderView in Interace Builder. When I start editing text in `UITextField`, `UITableViewCell` with `UITextField` disappear. They even disappear when compiling this xib in Interface Builder. Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it doesn't have to be inside table view cell. Try to use a regular UIView instead of the table view cell.

When exactly it disappears?
On keypad appearance or after typing the first char?

Comment: I want there to be UITableViewCell because of single line separator.
It disappears on keyboard appearance.